# Are there any hands on tools for visualizing knots other than strings?

Tags: soft-question, knot-theory

At a summer program I'm working at, high schoolers are learning some basic knot theory. Is string and tape the best way to go to help them visualize knots, or has anyone been successful with a more rigid (but not wire) material that perhaps doesn't use tape?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My colleague uses clay to sculpt knots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine did something similar and he used short extenstion cords.  Then you can plug them into themselves.  About 5 feet or so is probably a good length.  He said it worked well, but they are a little hard to manipulate at times too.

Good luck!

Comment: A variation on these would be the banana cables that get used in intro physics labs for plugging into multimeters. These have the advantage of being lightweight, clearly colored, and can be plugged into one another easily.